# How to create an Applescript to execute terminal commands and password

Tags: macos, terminal, passwords, applescript, osx-mavericks

I've searched around but couldn't quite find anything to fit my problem.

I want to create a script to replicate the following:

1. Open Terminal
2. Execute the following command:

   ```
   sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
   ```
3. Then have it enter my OSX admin password for me.
4. Then execute the following:

   ```
   sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
   ```

I'm completely new to applescript, so hoping someone can help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the "do shell script" command (it's from "StandardAdditions") - in AppleScript-Editor, open "Library" (see menu "Window") and double-click "StandardAdditions". Enter "do shell" into the Search-field.

Answer (score 4):

The hint in a comment on the question is correct (in [Apple]Script Editor, select `File > Open Dictionary...`, select `StandardAdditions.osax`, then search for `do shell script` to see the complete syntax), but it's important to note that **`do shell script` will NOT open a Terminal window; instead, it'll run the shell command hidden and return its result** - which is generally preferable:

- `do shell script`'s return value is the shell command's `stdout` output.
- If the shell command returns a non-zero exit code, AppleScript will throw an error and the error message will contain the command's `stderr` output.

To run commands with administrative privileges, you have 2 options:

- [**Recommended**] Let AppleScript **display a *password prompt***:

```applescript
set shCmds to "kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext;
kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext"

# This will prompt for an admin password, then execute the commands
# as if they had been run with `sudo`.
do shell script shCmds with administrator privileges
```

- [**Not recommended** for security reasons] Pass the **password as an argument**:

```applescript
set shCmds to "kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext;
kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext"

# Replace `{myPassword}` with your actual password.
# The commands will run as if they had been executed with `sudo`.
do shell script shCmds ¬
   user name short user name of (system info) password "{myPassword}" ¬
   with administrator privileges
```

As stated, if something goes wrong - whether it is because of an invalid password or a canceled password dialog or the shell commands returning a non-zero exit code - a runtime error is thrown.
Here's an example of trapping it and reporting it via `display alert`.

```applescript
try
    do shell script shCmds with administrator privileges
on error errMsg number errNo
    display alert "Executing '" & shCmds & "' failed with error code " & ¬
        errNo & " and the following message: " & errMsg
    return
end try
```

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 for the detailed reply. I will try this out and report back. What does adding error handling look like? (sorry I am not familiar with all this).

Comment: I gave it a try, I copy and pasted the first snippet and the error handling snippet and clicked run. The result was losing my sound controls and I fixed it by restarting. I may have been doing something wrong. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: @Adrius: If you run the same commands interactively in your Terminal, does it work? Would a delay between the unloading and loading help (insert `sleep 2` between the commands)? What are you trying to achieve? **If** this is about fixing loss of sound after waking a MacBook: _potential_ (haven't tried any, because I don't have the problem) workarounds such as "Deleting the 2 plist files in Macintosh HD > Library > Preferences > Audio and then rebooting seemed to solve the problem perfectly for me." can be found at
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5482053?start=180&tstart=0

Comment: That is exactly the issue I am trying to fix. When I run those commands separately it works. I can try adding `sleep 2` between the commands (just put it on a new line between the two?). I would try deleting the plist files, but I'm paranoid about deleting files. To the best of your knowledge would that break anything?

Comment: Re breaking: I don't know, but I don't think it would - if you try it, be sure to *move* them elsewhere first, so you can restore them. Re `sleep`: use `set shCmds to "kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext; sleep 2; kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext"`. Someone in the forum thread also mentioned **OnyX**, a great freeware maintenance utility, which you can use to clear cached information and see if that helps - http://www.titanium.free.fr/downloadonyx.php - "Do a clean sweep, especially of sound settings."